# Ender 3v2 stops mid-print

Tags: creality-ender-3

My Ender 3v2 stops mid-print; every print. The head just stops moving. The nozzle and bed temperatures are still on.

I then can cancel and start the job but it's stopping again, even when using totally different G-code files.

I'm using OctoPrint and didn't change anything lately. This never happened before.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Maybe try printing directly from SD card and see, if this problem still occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reinstalled the firmware and also reinstalled octoprint. Since then everything seems to be printing fine.